# How to disable babel transform-regenerator completely

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm looking for a way to completely disable generator functions transform with babel. With babel 5 there was a `blacklist` option, but it seems that with babel 6 there is no way to do that (at least I did not find any documentation on the official website).

My current configuration

```
{
  "presets": [
    "react",
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-object-rest-spread",   
  ]
}
```

Disabling it like described here https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-regenerator/ did not help.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looking for an answer to this myself, so adding a bounty.

Comment: You only have `react` preset in your current configuration which doesn't include `transform-regenerator` plugin in the first place.

Comment: @MarkKahn Well, it would've been better to ask your own question because, as Leonid mentioned, the React preset doesn't include the `transform-generator` plugin. I'm not sure how'd you'd get the `transform-generator` plugin in the first place unless you have the `env` preset or something else.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Have you tried "exclude"? Like:

```
{
   "presets": [
      ["env", {
         "exclude": ["transform-regenerator"]
      }]
   ]
}
```

Please see https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-env/#optionsexclude for details.