# Disabling Transpiler in Vue Webpack for Easier Debugging

Tags: javascript, debugging, vue.js, webpack, google-chrome-devtools

It is really hard to set breakpoints and step through code in Vue. I *think* this is because of the transpiling of javascript ES6/ES2015/ES2016/ES2017 to ES5. The source maps are mildly useful, but often when I "step" through, the cursor jumps around, leading me back to `console.log` debugging.

Since Chrome supports most of the latest features, I'd like to disable most or all transpiling for development.

I think what I need to do is add `transpileOptions` to vue-loader.conf.js (shown here):

```
var config = require('../config')
var isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'

module.exports = {
  loaders: utils.cssLoaders({
    sourceMap: isProduction
      ? config.build.productionSourceMap
      : config.dev.cssSourceMap,
    extract: isProduction
  })
}
```

Here are the Vue docs on [transpilerOptions](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/options.html#transpileoptions). The doc basically punts, and says, hey, refer to the [Buble options](https://buble.surge.sh/guide/#using-the-javascript-api).

I'm not sure how to proceed. Has anybody successfully disabled most transpiling for easier debugging?

Comment: I *may* have figured this out. It seems like most debug jumping stems from `async/await` calls. adding `"exclude": ["transform-regenerator"]` to my .babelrc as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43959126/how-to-disable-babel-transform-regenerator-completely seems to reduce jumping.

Answer (score 2):

I use Babel instead of Bublé for transpiling and I don't know much about Bublé so I hope this can help... What I did to make debugging easier is temporarily modify the `browserslist` in my `package.json` to support only the latest Chrome with `"last 1 chrome version"`. This removes most transpiling and polyfills from the build so it's easier to follow.

I'm guessing there is some sort of mechanism to specify which browsers you target and therefore what to polyfill in your setup as well. Give that a try and see if things are easier to debug.