# Does React or CRA optimize static statement? How to prevent static statement from getting optimized?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, babeljs, create-react-app

Let's consider the following code snippet, which is modified from the [React tutorial demo calculator](https://github.com/ahfarmer/calculator/blob/master/src/component/Button.js). There are two logging calls placed before assignment statement, respectively.

```js
export default class Button extends React.Component {
  // <= The newly added content
  static propTypes = (console.log("static statement executed"), {. 
    name: PropTypes.string,
    orange: PropTypes.bool,
    wide: PropTypes.bool,
    clickHandler: PropTypes.func,
  });
  // <= The newly added content
  member = (console.log("normal statement executed"), 1);  

  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.clickHandler(this.props.name);
  };

  render() {
    const className = [
      "component-button",
      this.props.orange ? "orange" : "",
      this.props.wide ? "wide" : "",
    ];

    return (
      <div className={className.join(" ").trim()}>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.props.name}</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

After the execution of `npm run build` and the examination of artifacts under `build/static/`, I found that the first logging statement associated with the static assignment vanished, while the second one was kept. Also, console of browser viewing the page did log the second message but not the first one.
[image]

So I wonder if React or CRA optimizes any static statements? If so, how can one prevent such statement from getting optimized?

Comment: interesting question; why do you want to prevent optimization?

Comment: @ch271828n Hi, I am using [nyc](https://istanbul.js.org/), the javascript coverage tool, to instrument my code. nyc makes use of counters before code lines to determine whether lines get executed or not. In my situation above, nyc actually inserts counters in static statement, but such counters disappeared during building and the resulting coverage data is wrong. I guess it has something to do with react or cra. And for simplicity, i use `console.log` to demonstrate my problem

Answer (score 1):

if you are creating a production build I believe propTypes are stripped. [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/3818) you can see the change in CRA. The plugin used is `babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types`. Hence why your second statement is evaluating but not the one under propTypes.

Comment: thx. I tried to use configuration mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45729942/8706476), but it didn't seem to work for me and the first statement still get optimized. Is there another way to disable this plugin?

Comment: Can you post your exclude statement? Make sure it’s in the package.json config file